# Función convertir de números a letras y optimización del código en Excel

Tags: excel, vba, lambda, office365, powerapps

La cuestión es la siguiente, con el lanzamiento de power toys, el lenguaje power fx y las funciones de LET y Lambda me decidí crear una función o UDF de convertir números a letras sin recurrir a las **macros o VBA**, por lo cual con prueba y error llegué a escribir el siguiente código.

Formato de barra de fórmulas de Excel

```
=LAMBDA(Numero_a_convertir;LET(NumerosM; REDONDEAR(SI(Numero_a_convertir < 0; Numero_a_convertir * -1; Numero_a_convertir); 0); Centenas; SI(ESNUMERO(NumerosM); SI.CONJUNTO(LARGO(NumerosM) = 3; BUSCARV(VALOR.NUMERO(EXTRAE(NumerosM; 1; 1) & REPETIR(0; LARGO(NumerosM) - 1)); {100\"Ciento";200\"Dosciento";300\"Treciento";400\"Cuatrociento";500\"Quinientos";600\"Seisciento";700\"Setecientos";800\"Ochocientos";900\"Novecientos"}; 2; FALSO); NumerosM < 100; ""); "No es un numero o el valor es negativo"); DTrucado; NumerosM - TRUNCAR(NumerosM; -2); Decenas; SI.CONJUNTO(Y(DTrucado >= 10; DTrucado <= 29); BUSCARV(DTrucado; {10\"diez";11\"Once";12\"Doce";13\"Trece";14\"Catorce";15\"Quince";16\"Dieciséis";17\"Diecisiete";18\"Dieciocho";19\"Diecinueve";20\"veinte";21\"Veintiuno";22\"Veintidós";23\"Veintitrés";24\"Veinticuatro";25\"Veinticinco";26\"Veintiséis";27\"Veintisiete";28\"Veintiocho";29\"Veintinueve"}; 2; FALSO); DTrucado > 10; BUSCARV(VALOR.NUMERO(EXTRAE(DTrucado; 1; 1) & REPETIR(0; 1)); {10\"Diez";20\"Veinte";30\"Treinta";40\"Cuarenta";50\"Cincuenta";60\"Sesenta";70\"Setenta";80\"Ochenta";90\"Noventa"}; 2; FALSO); O(DTrucado = 0; DTrucado < 10); ""); Utrucado; NumerosM - TRUNCAR(NumerosM; -1); Unidades; SI.CONJUNTO(Y(Utrucado >= 1; Utrucado <= 9); BUSCARV(Utrucado; {1\"Uno";2\"Dos";3\"Tres";4\"Cuatro";5\"Cinco";6\"Seis";7\"Siete";8\"Ocho";9\"Nueve"}; 2; FALSO)); Digito; SI(Y(Centenas = ""; Decenas = ""); Unidades; " y " & Unidades); SI.CONJUNTO(NumerosM = 0; "cero"; Decenas = 100; "cien"; NumerosM >= 1000; "El numero supera el limite de la formula"; Y(DTrucado >= 10; DTrucado <= 29); ESPACIOS((Centenas & " " & Decenas)); Y(DTrucado > 29; Utrucado = 0); ESPACIOS((Centenas & " " & Decenas)); VERDADERO(); ESPACIOS(Centenas & " " & Decenas & Digito))))
```

Formato Excel labs Advanced formula environment

```
=LAMBDA(Numero_a_convertir;
LET(
    NumerosM; REDONDEAR(
        SI(
            Numero_a_convertir < 0;
            Numero_a_convertir * -1;
            Numero_a_convertir
        );
        0
    );
    Centenas; SI(
        ESNUMERO(NumerosM);
        SI.CONJUNTO(
            LARGO(NumerosM) = 3;
            BUSCARV(
                VALOR.NUMERO(
                    EXTRAE(
                        NumerosM;
                        1;
                        1
                    ) &
                        REPETIR(
                            0;
                            LARGO(
                                NumerosM
                            ) - 1
                        )
                );
                {
                    100\ "Ciento";
                    200\ "Dosciento";
                    300\ "Treciento";
                    400\ "Cuatrociento";
                    500\ "Quinientos";
                    600\ "Seisciento";
                    700\ "Setecientos";
                    800\ "Ochocientos";
                    900\ "Novecientos"
                };
                2;
                FALSO
            );
            NumerosM < 100;
            ""
        );
        "No es un numero"
    );
    DTrucado; NumerosM -
        TRUNCAR(NumerosM; -2);
    Decenas; SI.CONJUNTO(
        Y(DTrucado >= 10; DTrucado <= 29);
        BUSCARV(
            DTrucado;
            {
                10\ "diez";
                11\ "Once";
                12\ "Doce";
                13\ "Trece";
                14\ "Catorce";
                15\ "Quince";
                16\ "Dieciséis";
                17\ "Diecisiete";
                18\ "Dieciocho";
                19\ "Diecinueve";
                20\ "veinte";
                21\ "Veintiuno";
                22\ "Veintidós";
                23\ "Veintitrés";
                24\ "Veinticuatro";
                25\ "Veinticinco";
                26\ "Veintiséis";
                27\ "Veintisiete";
                28\ "Veintiocho";
                29\ "Veintinueve"
            };
            2;
            FALSO
        );
        DTrucado > 10;
        BUSCARV(
            VALOR.NUMERO(
                EXTRAE(DTrucado; 1; 1) &
                    REPETIR(0; 1)
            );
            {
                10\ "Diez";
                20\ "Veinte";
                30\ "Treinta";
                40\ "Cuarenta";
                50\ "Cincuenta";
                60\ "Sesenta";
                70\ "Setenta";
                80\ "Ochenta";
                90\ "Noventa"
            };
            2;
            FALSO
        );
        O(DTrucado = 0; DTrucado < 10);
        ""
    );
    Utrucado; NumerosM -
        TRUNCAR(NumerosM; -1);
    Unidades; SI.CONJUNTO(
        Y(Utrucado >= 1; Utrucado <= 9);
        BUSCARV(
            Utrucado;
            {
                1\ "Uno";
                2\ "Dos";
                3\ "Tres";
                4\ "Cuatro";
                5\ "Cinco";
                6\ "Seis";
                7\ "Siete";
                8\ "Ocho";
                9\ "Nueve"
            };
            2;
            FALSO
        )
    );
    Digito; SI(
        Y(Centenas = ""; Decenas = "");
        Unidades;
        " y " & Unidades
    );
    SI.CONJUNTO(
        NumerosM = 0;
        "cero";
        Decenas = 100;
        "cien";
        NumerosM >= 1000;
        "El numero supera el limite de la formula";
        Y(DTrucado >= 10; DTrucado <= 29);
        ESPACIOS(
            (Centenas & " " & Decenas)
        );
        Y(DTrucado > 29; Utrucado = 0);
        ESPACIOS(
            (Centenas & " " & Decenas)
        );
        VERDADERO();
        ESPACIOS(
            Centenas & " " & Decenas &
                Digito
        )
    )
)
```

)

La cuestión es la siguiente, ¿cómo puedo optimizarlo para aumentar la capacidad de la formula ya que este llega hasta 999, es posible reutilizar las variables si tener la necesidad de volver escribir el mismo código agregando mil o millones?